# change the state of a textbox depending on which view is called

Tags: textbox, asp.net-mvc-5, conditional-statements, enable-if

I'm new to MVC, and would like to know in C# mvc5, what kind of code I would need to use, if I wanted to change the state of a textbox from enabled to disabled and vice versa based on which view is calling the partial view.

Comment: Are we talking one control? or a whole host of controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add something like this in your tag:  `@('Condition Here') ? disabled:"disabled" : ""`

Or:

```
object mode = ('Condition Here') ? null : new {disabled = "disabled" };
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.YourPropertyHere, mode)
```